# Setting NULL as default results in 1067 error Invalid default value for 'created'

Tags: mysql, default-settings, phpmyadmin

Trying to set the default value of a column to NULL results in 1067 error: Invalid default value for 'created'.

Comment: This field is set to some date/time datatype? Check server's [SQL modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-full), especially NO_ZERO_DATE and NO_ZERO_IN_DATE.

Comment: ok so i looked further, it seems 'created' is another column - and when I tried to set that nulls, it gave an error on another date/time column